# XPath, how to select a parent node which has to satisfy two attributes of child 1?

Tags: xpath

I would like to select all b where `c2attr > 5` on `c2 = text2`. In Xpath, I wrote:

```
a/b[c2 = text2 and c2attr >5]
```

However, it did not give me the condition that both satisfy when `c2=text2`, `c2attr >5`. 
It gave me every c2 element which has `c2attr >5`. How should I write to correctly select
b?

for example:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c1>c1 text</c1>
        <c2 c2attr="3">text1</c2>
        <c2 c2attr="8">tex2</c2>
        <c2 c2attr="50">text3</c2>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c1>c1 text</b1>
        <c2 c2attr="1">text4</c2>
        <c2 c2attr="6">tex2</c2>
        <c2 c2attr="10">text1</c2>
    </b>
</a>
```

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `c2 = text2` to `c2 = 'text2'` since you're comparing strings, and add the attribute specifier `@` for `c2attr` like so:

```
a/b[c2[text() = 'tex2'  and @c2attr > 5]]
```

Also, your XML is invalid, not sure if typo but you have a `<c1>` node closed with `<b1>`, and it also does not contain text with "text2", it's missing the last 't' there.